# Append Values of Button on Click on Input Type

Tags: jquery

How can I append the value of the button on click to ***delete_id_receiver***   text field. The output should be 1,2,3 if the 3 buttons are click.

And change the value of delete button to "UNDO" and remove the values on the text input.

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <td><button onclick="deleteVal(1)" type="button"> Delete </button></td>
    <td> John </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><button onclick="deleteVal(2)" type="button"> Delete </button></td>
    <td> May </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><button onclick="deleteVal(3)" type="button"> Delete </button></td>
    <td> Andrew </td>
</tr>
```

```
<input type="text" id="delete_id_receiver">
```

This is what i've tried but it does not stock the id's on click

```
 function deleteVal(val){
      var delete_id = val;
     document.getElementById('delete_id_receiver').value = val; 
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You almost there. Just missing to add previous value . Use : `+=`

```js
function deleteVal(val) {
  var delete_id = val;
  document.getElementById('delete_id_receiver').value += val + ',';
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td><button onclick="deleteVal(1)" type="button"> Delete </button></td>
    <td> John </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button onclick="deleteVal(2)" type="button"> Delete </button></td>
    <td> May </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button onclick="deleteVal(3)" type="button"> Delete </button></td>
    <td> Andrew </td>
  </tr>
  <input type="text" id="delete_id_receiver">
```

Comment: how can i put a comma in between? 1,2,3

Comment: It is duplicating the values if I click a button more than once.

Answer (score 2):

Below solution is able to append, UNDO with no duplicates and no unnecessary commas.

```js
function deleteVal(val){
   var buttonText = document.getElementById(val).innerText.trim();

   if(buttonText == 'Delete')
   {
      var valueToAppend = val;
      var valueInsideTextbox = document.getElementById('delete_id_receiver').value;
    
      if(valueInsideTextbox.includes(valueToAppend))
     return;
      
      if(valueInsideTextbox.trim() != "")
     valueToAppend = "," + valueToAppend;
      
      document.getElementById('delete_id_receiver').value = valueInsideTextbox + valueToAppend;
      document.getElementById(val).innerText = 'UNDO';
   }
   else if(buttonText == 'UNDO')
   {
     var valueToRemove = val;
     var valueInsideTextbox = document.getElementById('delete_id_receiver').value;
    
     if(valueInsideTextbox.trim() != "" && valueInsideTextbox.includes(valueToRemove))
     {
     valueInsideTextbox = valueInsideTextbox.replace("," + val, "").replace(val + ",", "").replace(val, "");
     } 
     document.getElementById('delete_id_receiver').value = valueInsideTextbox;
     document.getElementById(val).innerText = 'Delete';
   }
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <td><button id="1" onclick="deleteVal(1)" type="button"> Delete 
</button></td>
    <td> John </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><button id="2" onclick="deleteVal(2)" type="button"> Delete </button></td>
    <td> May </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><button id="3" onclick="deleteVal(3)" type="button"> Delete 
    </button></td>
    <td> Andrew </td>
</tr>
<input type="text" id="delete_id_receiver">
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to prevent duplicate values being stored is to create an `array` to store the current delete values/ids

You can then use the `Array.join` function to join them with commas

```js
var deleteVals = [];
function deleteVal(val) {
  var delete_id = val;
  
  // check if delete_id is not contained within deleteVals
  if(deleteVals.indexOf(delete_id) === -1){
    deleteVals.push(delete_id);
  }
  
  // call the update function to update the value of #delete_id_receiver
  updateDeleteVals();
}

function updateDeleteVals(){
  document.getElementById('delete_id_receiver').value = deleteVals.join(",");
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td><button onclick="deleteVal(1)" type="button"> Delete </button></td>
    <td> John </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button onclick="deleteVal(2)" type="button"> Delete </button></td>
    <td> May </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button onclick="deleteVal(3)" type="button"> Delete </button></td>
    <td> Andrew </td>
  </tr>
  <input type="text" id="delete_id_receiver">
```

Comment: almost ok but how can I change the delete button to undo and remove the values in textfield. VICE VERSA

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```js
function deleteVal(val) {
  var delete_id = val;
  var delete_id_receiver = document.getElementById('delete_id_receiver').value
  if(!delete_id_receiver.includes(delete_id)){
     var tempVal = document.getElementById('delete_id_receiver').value += val + ',';
     document.getElementById('delete_id_receiver').value = tempVal;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td><button onclick="deleteVal(1)" type="button"> Delete </button></td>
    <td> John </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button onclick="deleteVal(2)" type="button"> Delete </button></td>
    <td> May </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button onclick="deleteVal(3)" type="button"> Delete </button></td>
    <td> Andrew </td>
  </tr>
  <input type="text" id="delete_id_receiver">
```

Comment: can you help me do the switching of the delete button text to undo and remove the values in text field. and then vice versa

Answer (score 0):

try this if you want value as 1,2,3

```js
function deleteVal(val){ 
  current_val  = document.getElementById('delete_id_receiver').value;
  
  if(current_val==""){
  document.getElementById('delete_id_receiver').value = current_val+""+val; 
  }else if(val=="del"){
  document.getElementById('delete_id_receiver').value = ""

    }
    else{
       document.getElementById('delete_id_receiver').value = current_val+", "+val; 
    }
  
    
 }
```

```html
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <td><button onclick="deleteVal(1)" type="button"> Delete </button></td>
    <td> John </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><button onclick="deleteVal(2)" type="button"> Delete </button></td>
    <td> May </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><button onclick="deleteVal(3)" type="button"> Delete </button></td>
    <td> Andrew </td>
</tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><button onclick="deleteVal('del')" type="button"> Undo </button></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
  
  <input type="text" id="delete_id_receiver">
```